# Make annotation on graph created by echart

Tags: reactjs

I'm using reactJs to develop the frontend, is it possible to make annotations on graphs created by **echart**? For example, I can left-click anywhere on a line chart to make a quick note of that point or I can a range on a graph and make a note of that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to build an interface that allows users to left-click somewhere on the chart and add their own annotations (rather simply coding in annotations as a developer, and having them be static)?

In broad strokes, here's how I would build this:

1. Register [click event handlers on the chart](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/10020), so you can detect where the user clicked.
2. Build custom UI in react that can overlay on the chart, provide text input and "add"/"cancel" buttons, using the information from the click event to figure out where to draw it and to what element the annotation should be attached to.
3. When the user clicks "add", make a call to the `showTip` API (see [docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.tooltip.showTip)) to a tooltip in the right location (from step 1) with the text the user provided.

(It looks like there is [a github issue where folks are asking for this feature to be built-in](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/10020) - and some discussion of how to build it yourself, and a [simple example that illustrates how to do step 3 above](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=line-draggable) which you might find useful)